# Cloudformation !Ref doesn't return the correct value for vpc endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have a vpc endpoint created with:

```
  ExecuteApiVPCEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action:
              - "execute-api:*"
            Resource:
              - "*"
      ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.execute-api
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      VpcEndpointType: Interface
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref privateSubnet01
        - !Ref privateSubnet02
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref EndpointSG # has to allow traffic from your VPC
      PrivateDnsEnabled: true
```

and a private API created with:

```
  APIDefinition:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Api'
    Properties:
      StageName: {Ref: Stage}
      EndpointConfiguration: PRIVATE
      Auth:
        ResourcePolicy:
          CustomStatements:
            - Action: ['execute-api:Invoke']
              Effect: Allow
              Principal: '*'
              Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:/*/*/*"
            - Action: ['execute-api:Invoke']
              Effect: Deny
              Principal: '*'
              Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:/*/*/*"
              Condition:
                ForAllValues:StringNotEquals:
                  aws:sourceVpce:
                  - !Ref ExecuteApiVPCEndpoint
```

The stack was deployed with no error, but the vpce in the resource policy of the API doesn't match with the vpce being created. What's going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying the VPCE referenced becomes a different VPCE? But a valid one. Are these in the same stack?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same stack. The vpce value in the resource policy looks like a "valid" one (with the same format), but I can't find it anywhere in the vpc endpoint list (within VPC service). I checked other regions too, and it's not there either. Any idea what could have happened?

Comment: @Katie can you check in the `cloudformation` console, if there is resource created for this, if yes then that resource will be a link. That can help.